# sass --watch is not watching for updates (only update when first run)

Tags: css, sass, watch

when I type sass --watch in cmd it converts the file to css but does not watch for any updates that I make in the scss. In terminal it says
"Compiled style.scss to ..\css\style.css.
Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop."
Tried to use methods through the stackoverflow answers on the similar topics but that didn't work out for me

Comment: Not sure if it'll help but I usually specifically tell sass which files to watch. So, in your case it would be sass --watch css/style.scss considering that css is in your current folder right now.

Comment: I'm writing in cmd : "sass --watch style.scss:../css/style.css "

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was in Cyrillic name of my folder